# What do the dotted lines represent in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

While I still struggle with constraints in xcode it's getting easier. Something that I haven't been able to find out more information is when I add constraints to my design objects I sometimes get a dotted outline somewhere other then where the object is sitting, and I'm not quite sure what that is. [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the orange dashed lines represents the frame that your component will be in because of the constrains you have added to it to make every component go to it's correct place select the top level view in your viewController press Editor -> update frames

While if you have a red lines that represent you have added conflicting frames like you say a button width is 50 and another constrains says it's width is 100 so then you have 2 conflicting constrains and the component can't calculate it's frame so review your constrains then

the blue ones says that every thing is fine with your constraints

Hope my answer helps you